# What is causing the new line character to not work in my program?

Tags: arrays, c, string

I am not sure why my new line is not working for `printf(operand1, "%s\n");` I print test afterwards and its not on a new line.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  printf("Enter elementary operation:"); //Output to console for user to see
  char input[32]; //Create a char array of size 32 characters (32 bytes or 256 bits), can only store 255 due to needing the end string character which is '\0'
  fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin); //get line that user inputs
  printf(input,"%s\n"); //print the string the user input
  char operand1[32];
  int i = 0;

  while(input[i] == '0' || input[i] == '.' || input[i] == '1' || input[i] == '2' || input[i] == '3' || input[i] == '4'
|| input[i] == '5' || input[i] == '6' || input[i] == '7' || input[i] == '8' || input[i] == '9' || (i == 0 && input[i] == '-')){

    operand1[i] = input[i];
    i++;

  }

  printf(operand1, "%s\n");
  printf("test");
  return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
Enter elementary operation:99+0

99+0

99test%
```

Comment: Compile with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your executable

Comment: The arguments of `printf(operand1, "%s\n");` are in the wrong order - format string goes first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it should be `printf("%s\n",operand1)`. What happens in your code is that `operand1` is treated as format string and since it doesn't have `%` in it, it is printed as is.

Second, your `operand1` doesn't have zero byte after the copied chars, so it's not really a string from C's point of view and when you pass it to `printf` with `%s` format option `printf` will print your memory content until it accidentally hits a 0. Although, perhaps this behavior won't happen, because when you allocate an array it might be pre-initialized with zeros - depends on lots of things. It is more correct and safe to add `operand1[i] = '\0'` after the loop

Third, there is `isdigit` function (defined in `<ctype.h>`), that you can use i/o testing manually for all the digits. Or you can use comparison `(input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= '9')`

Comment: Thank you for the input! Okay, that makes sense that its not interpreted as a string since there might not be a null terminator. I assume when you use scanf and fgets it adds the null terminator at the end automatically?

Comment: That's correct, scanf and fgets return zero-terminated string. All standard function working with strings do. But the main problem is the order of the arguments in the call to printf. Btw, if you know for sure that your string doesn't contain percent sign, you can do printf(mystr) w/o the format string, although it is frowned upon.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Yeah I am a little bit sleepy as I practice my C programming and mixed the order up!